# I work on Friday vs I work on Fridays

Tags: present-tense, future

I found a grammar book that states the following:

[image]

(Grammar In Use Intermediate by Cambridge unit 18 pg.36 Present Tenses )

Which means that it is OK to use the simple present form to describe the future with fixed schedules.

But is it also OK to use the simple present to talk about fixed schedules that are not future?

Here is an example of a Japanese Jr. High English textbook (Level 1 New Horizon by Tokyo Shoseki 23rd year of Heisei Unit 3 Pg. 31)

[image]

In this example it says,

> A: Do you come to school every day?
>   B: No, I don't. I come to school on Tuesday and Friday.

But if she only comes on Tuesdays would it be OK to say,

> I come to school on Tuesday

Or should she say,

> I come to school on Tuesdays?

I am not looking for an answer that is an opinion. I need to have a sited text from a legitimate published work that has an example of using the simple present with a day of the week in the singular form. This has to do with a student's paper. I cannot grade it based on conjecture.

Comment: There are 2 abouts in your book. I don't have a clue why.

Comment: I think it can depend on context. If you are already into a discussion with someone about which day you might be available for regular contact, you could say *It would have to be Thursday, because I work Friday*. But if you are simply talking about your lifestyle in general then you would need, in order to be idiomatic, to say *I work on Fridays*.

Comment: I have to have evidence backed by a PhD to support the answer. Otherwise it's just speculation. This has to do with students grades.

Comment: That's a very strange requirement. Can you explain a little - are you grading the students, or is this to query a grade already issued? Also, you've edited the question to remove the quoted text;  if the link to your picture fails, the question will make little sense.

Comment: Sorry. Deleting the transcription was a mistake. The picture I uploaded directly to this site so it is not linked. I the answer cannot be simply a matter of how someone feels is correct or not. I'm grading a paper that is being disputed and I need evidence to make my case.

Comment: After having time to think about what I'm asking, I've realized that the original question needed a complete overhaul. If anyone has a sited reference with a weekday in singular form used with the simple present, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Would a newspaper be sufficient? Or a work of fiction?